# How to combine templates and radio buttons in knockoutjs scripts?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to show a group of radio buttons using knockoutjs. I also want to have one of the radio buttons selected based on a certain value and know the value of the selected radio button in case someone selects a different item.

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
<form>
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'items-template', foreach: items }"></div>

    <h3 data-bind="text: selectedItem"></h3>
</form>

</body>
<script type="text/html" id="items-template">
    <input type="radio" name="skuitem" data-bind="value: id, checked: selectedItem"><span data-bind="text: name"></span><br /></input>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ItemsViewModel() {

        var _this = this;

        _this.items = ko.observableArray();
        _this.items.push({id: "1", name: "Item A"});
        _this.items.push({id: "7", name: "Item B"});
        _this.items.push({id: "10", name: "Item C"});

        _this.selectedItem = ko.observable("1");
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new ItemsViewModel());
</script>
```

The problem is that I get an error in the console:

```
ReferenceError: selectedItem is not defined
```

From what I understand, knockout looks into the objects contained in the items array for "selectedItem" instead of binding to the "selectedItem" variable in my ItemsViewModel.

How can I bind my radio buttons to the selectedItem observable when I'm using templates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your template, your binding context is an `item`, you'll only have `id` and `name` available to link to directly.

Any properties in the `ItemsViewModel` can be accessed using `$parent` or `$root`.

So, you'll have to write: `data-bind="value: id, checked: $parent.selectedItem"`

```js
function ItemsViewModel() {

  var _this = this;

  _this.items = ko.observableArray();
  _this.items.push({
    id: "1",
    name: "Item A"
  });
  _this.items.push({
    id: "7",
    name: "Item B"
  });
  _this.items.push({
    id: "10",
    name: "Item C"
  });

  _this.selectedItem = ko.observable("1");
}

ko.applyBindings(new ItemsViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div data-bind="template: { name: 'items-template', foreach: items }"></div>

  <h3 data-bind="text: selectedItem"></h3>
</form>

<script type="text/html" id="items-template">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" data-bind="value: id, 
                                   checked: $parent.selectedItem" />
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </label>
</script>
```

Instead of solving the issue in the view, you can also solve it in your models. You can pass a reference to the selection observable to each `item`:

```js
function ItemsViewModel() {

  var _this = this;

  _this.items = ko.observableArray();
  _this.selectedItem = ko.observable("1");

  _this.items.push({
    id: "1",
    name: "Item A",
    selectedItem: _this.selectedItem
  });
  _this.items.push({
    id: "7",
    name: "Item B",
    selectedItem: _this.selectedItem
  });
  _this.items.push({
    id: "10",
    name: "Item C",
    selectedItem: _this.selectedItem
  });

}

ko.applyBindings(new ItemsViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div data-bind="template: { name: 'items-template', foreach: items }"></div>

  <h3 data-bind="text: selectedItem"></h3>
</form>

<script type="text/html" id="items-template">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" data-bind="value: id, 
                                   checked: selectedItem"/>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </label>
</script>
```